# embedding php in javascript to switch out image in child theme

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to embed a some php in my javascript to switch out images...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.small-port-images a:nth-child(3)').click(function() {
    $('.large-port-image img').attr('src', '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/images/large-brigham.jpg');
    });
});
```

I believe I am missing something, for this is not working. Any advice?

Comment: where are you trying to do this? an action hook, a template file, a .js file?

Comment: What's not working about it? Does the stylesheet directory uri not print, leaving your img src with "/images/..."? Does the JS not work?

Comment: I ended up simply hardcoding it like this

$('.large-port-image img').attr('src', '.../wp-content/uploads/2013/05/large-mockport.jpg');

And that worked. The code was in my .js file. I was under the impression one could embed php within a js file? Am I wrong?